# Fade 3 divs in and out sequentially

Tags: html, css, animation, sass

I am trying to animate 3 divs one at a time to fade in and out. I would like the first one to fade in, pause for 2 seconds then fade out. Then the second one should fade in, pause for 2 seconds then fade out followed by the third div doing the same. Right now the animation is not working and the divs are not fading in at all. Below is the html and css being used for the animation.

```
<div class="fave-animate rag-and-bone-container">
  <img class="rag-and-bone" src="/assets/images/rag-and-bone-boot.png"></img>
  <div class="title">
    <strong translate>Rag & Bone</strong>
    <span translate>just for you.</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="fave-animate asos-container">
  <img class="asos" src="/assets/images/asos.png"></img>
  <div class="title asos">
    <strong translate>Asos</strong>
    <span translate>just for you.</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="fave-animate style-container">
  <img class="style-inspiration" src="/assets/images/style-inspiration.png"></img>
  <div class="title style">
    <strong translate>Style inspiration</strong>
    <span translate>just for you.</span>
  </div>
</div>


.fave-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 544px;
  opacity: 0;

  .fave-animate {
    -webkit-animation-name: demo;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;

    &.rag-and-bone-container {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
    }

    &.asos-container {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
    }

    &.style-container {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
    }
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes demo {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
    }

    50% {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
```

Comment: In my opinion you would be better off using JQuery, your CSS is very browser specific and will have limited support.

Comment: i can extend it to other browsers i just need to figure out how to make the fading work first

Comment: IT fades in chrome ... but the timing is the tricky part

Answer (score 0):

Your animation sequence doesn't match the requirement.

This is supposed to happen over 10 seconds

```
 @-webkit-keyframes demo {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
    }

    50% {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
```

There is no pause here..once the sequence reaches 50% it immediately starts working back to 0 opacity. So the actual sequence should look like...

```
 @-webkit-keyframes demo {
    0% {
      opacity: 0; /* take 4 seconds */
    }

    40% {
      opacity: 1; /* pauses for 2 seconds (20% of 10 seconds) */
    }

    60% {
      opacity: 1; /* still at full opacity but now resumes taking another 4 second */
    }

    100% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
```

You can also remove the timing function.

Comment: That makes alot more sense but the only animation i see still is all 3 divs flashing at once and not fading

Comment: See - http://jsfiddle.net/xy0s9xfu/6/ in Chrome...prefix as required. It's not perfect but it will get you closer.

Comment: ya thats almost exactly what i want, i guess i was unclear in the requirements but once one div fades out, it should not fade back in with the next one. It should just fade in one at a time.

Comment: Updated now fiddle in previous comment. The timing is always going to be hard because the transitions will always overlap. In fact what you are after is a 30second animation (3*10 seconds) not 10 seconds..and everything would need to be adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Using the & you where telling the css that reg and asos are children of fave when they are not, they are fave.

Here is a sample of three divs behaving in such an animation you should be able to cope with it from here.

http://jsfiddle.net/qdnsz1p8/1/

```
.fave-animate {
background:red;
padding:60px;
margin-right:10px;
width:40px; 
float:left;
-webkit-animation: demo ease-in-out 5s infinite;
}

div.rag-and-bone-container {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
}

div.asos-container {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}

div.style-container {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes demo {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```